# Setting the executable bit on files in Mercurial

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I've seen it mentioned that mercurial stores the executable bit on files, but cannot find out how to do it. I'm looking for functionality analogous to `svn ps svn:executable '' TARGET`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Set (or unset) the executable bit on the file, and then hg will mark it as modified.  Commit it.

You will need to enable git-style diffs to see the modes in diff output, but it's still there regardless.

Comment: I do not have this same experience with Mercurial 2.7.1. For me changing the executable flag on the file does not change the status of that file.

Comment: This doesn't work on Windows, which doesn't have such notion - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702825/setting-mercurials-execute-bit-on-windows

Answer (score 2):

For Linux or Unix you could use `chmod +x filename`.

For Windows you need to create a patch file and then apply it using the `--bypass` argument to `hg import`. This could be done by creating a Powershell script file called `SetFileExecutable.ps1`, with the text below

```
param (
  [String]$comment = "+execbit",
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$fileRelativePath,
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$repositoryRoot
)

$fileRelativePath = $fileRelativePath.Replace( '\', '/' )

$diff = "$comment" + [System.Environment]::NewLine +
  [System.Environment]::NewLine +
  "diff --git a/$fileRelativePath b/$fileRelativePath" + [System.Environment]::NewLine +
  "old mode 100644" + [System.Environment]::NewLine +
  "new mode 100755"

Push-Location
cd $repositoryRoot
$diff | Out-File -Encoding 'utf8' $env:tmp\exebit.diff
hg import --bypass -m "$comment" $env:tmp\exebit.diff
Pop-Location
```

execute it as follows:

```
.\SetFileExecutable.ps1" -comment "Marking file as executable" -fileRelativePath mvnw -repositoryRoot "c:\myrepo"
```

The uses the solution provided by [Matt Harbison in Mercurial's Bugzilla](https://bz.mercurial-scm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2020#c8)