# Setting Mercurial's execute bit on Windows

Tags: windows, mercurial, cross-platform, filesystems, fat32

I work on a Mercurial repository that is checked out onto an Unix filesystem such as ext3 on some machines, and FAT32 on others.

In Subversion, I can set the svn:executable property to control whether a file should be marked executable when checked out on a platform that supports such a bit. I can do this regardless of the platform I'm running SVN on or the filesystem containing my working copy.

In Mercurial, I can chmod +x to get the same effect if the clone is on a Unix filesystem. But how can I set (or remove) the executable bit on a file on a FAT filesystem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mercurial tracks the execute bit as part of the file metdata.  There's no way to explictly set it in mercurial, but it tracks changes made by `chmod` on unix.  Files added on windows will have the execute bit set by default, but the windows attrib command doesn't let you set them.

If you do a `hg log -p --git` you'll see the patch format that shows the altering of the execute bit, which looks like this:

```
$ hg log --git -p
changeset:   1:0d9a70aadc0a
tag:         tip
user:        Ry4an Brase <ry4an-hg@ry4an.org>
date:        Sat Apr 24 10:05:23 2010 -0500
summary:     added execute

diff --git a/that b/that
old mode 100644
new mode 100755

changeset:   0:06e25cb66089
user:        Ry4an Brase <ry4an-hg@ry4an.org>
date:        Sat Apr 24 10:05:09 2010 -0500
summary:     added no execute

diff --git a/that b/that
new file mode 100644
--- /dev/null
+++ b/that
@@ -0,0 +1,1 @@
+this
```

If you're not able to get on to a unix system to set them, you could probably fake up a patch like that and `hg import` it, but that's definitely sub optimal.

Comment: I tried using this technique when adding a file and it did not work. I added the file, created the patch, reverted the repo, removed the file, edited the patch replacing 0644 with 0755, and imported the patch. When pulling on a Unix system, the mode is still 0644. Mercurial 1.9.1.

Comment: The pull doesn't create the file, the update does.  After you've pulled and you do a 'hg log --git -p' do you see the 100755 in the patch?  When you update that execute bit could be unset if the umask prohibits it, the file system is mounted no-execute, or a few other unlikely things.

Comment: In looking at the log, it shows the 0644 mode, so for some reason, it didn't accept the mode from the edited patch.

Comment: Hrm, and you used the actual 'hg import' command, right?  Not the command line 'patch' tool?

Comment: Correct. I'm going to have to try to reproduce it.

Comment: @Ry4an: I tried this solution a while ago. Unfortunately, Mercurial on Windows simply ignores file mode changes in patches, there is really no way to set the executable bit.

Comment: Here is evidence in the form of [a transcript](http://paste.jaraco.com/F7wjP) to confirm my findings that this technique will not work.

Answer (score 9):

For the time being you cannot change the execute bit if the filesystem doesn't support it (I have plan to support it in the future).

Comment: The issue 3659 was closed as duplicate, the older one is: https://bz.mercurial-scm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2020

Comment: This is a showstopper with Windows + Linux cooperation, and I find it mindboggling that nobody has written an extension to work this out. Even this question is six years old...

Answer (score 5):

For Windows you need to create a patch file and then apply it, like [Ry4an has said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2704912/664054), but with the `--bypass` argument to `hg import`. This could be done by creating a Powershell script file called `SetFileExecutable.ps1` with the text below inside it

```
param (
  [String]$comment = "+execbit",
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$filePathRelativeTo,
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$repositoryRoot
)

if( Test-Path -Path "$($repositoryRoot)\.hg" -PathType Container )
{
  if( Test-Path -Path "$($repositoryRoot)\$($filePathRelativeTo)" -PathType Leaf )
  {
    $filePathRelativeTo = $filePathRelativeTo.Replace( '\', '/' )

    $diff = "$comment" + [System.Environment]::NewLine +
      [System.Environment]::NewLine +
      "diff --git a/$filePathRelativeTo b/$filePathRelativeTo" + [System.Environment]::NewLine +
      "old mode 100644" + [System.Environment]::NewLine +
      "new mode 100755"

    Push-Location
    cd $repositoryRoot
    $diff | Out-File -Encoding 'utf8' $env:tmp\exebit.diff
    hg import --bypass -m "$comment" $env:tmp\exebit.diff
    Pop-Location
  }
  else
  {
    Write-Host "filePathRelativeTo must the location of a file relative to repositoryRoot"
  }
}
else
{
  Write-Host "repositoryRoot must be the location of the .hg folder"
}
```

execute it as follows:

```
.\SetFileExecutable.ps1" -comment "Marking file as executable" -filePathRelativeTo mvnw -repositoryRoot "c:\myrepo"
```

The uses the solution provided by [Matt Harbison in Mercurial's Bugzilla](https://bz.mercurial-scm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2020#c8)

Comment: There's a typo in your script, need to change `filePathRelativeTo` -> `fileRelativePath`, otherwise it does its job, thanks :)

Comment: @joonas.fi sorry I forgot to update this after I fix that issue.

Comment: No worries, happens to all of us :) p.s. in the "execute it as follows" it's still the wrong way around (`fileRelativePathTo ` vs `filePathRelativeTo` in the script)